# Nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar UIImagePicker

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using the UIImagePicker to select a photo from the users photo library.

Here is my setup:

MenuViewController (UINavigationController class) that has a tweet button.

Click the tweet button, it presents modally a custom tweet composer.

Select the "Camera Roll" button and I call UIPickerView which is also presented modally.

When you select camera roll (or any album) I get this error:

```
2013-08-03 02:25:41.842 appName[2145:f803] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
```

and my custom back button now looks like this:

[image: Corrupted Back Button in Nav]

instead of:

[image]

Here is the code that displays the tweet composer:

```
- (IBAction)tweetButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    KBTweetComposer *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"new_tweet"];

    vc.defaultText = @"";

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Here is how I'm presenting the picker view:

```
- (void)photosButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I am using storyboards, but I am not using segues, just as a side note. I have found quite a few different people on StackOverflow who have the same error but a completely different circumstance.

It may be related to Presenting a UIViewController that then presents another UINavigationController (The UIImagePicker by default has a Nav Controller) in addition to the original.

How can I get around this? Any help would be great, thanks!